# GIt still showing deleted files

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit, git-push

After trying, `git push origin master` , I got the results as:

```
Enumerating objects: 1929, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1929/1929), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (116/116), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1911/1911), 941.12 MiB | 58.52 MiB/s, done.
Total 1911 (delta 1830), reused 1869 (delta 1794), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1830/1830), completed with 17 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 86df591ef0a82a8657774c9b90683e3c2b0df3ffb91ee64f4fd1d41337a73977
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File media/CA211117.ZIP is 762.66 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/rikesh1212/spider.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rikesh1212/spider.git'
```

I don't have any file `media/CA211117.ZIP`. While trying:

```
git rm -r media/CA211117.ZIP
```

Got:

```
fatal: pathspec 'media/CA211117.zip' did not match any files
```

Now I cannot push anything because of this error. How to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history

Comment: not that question, find a specific one